# NodeJS watcher printing undefined after logging function to console

Tags: node.js

I am playing around with NodeJS watchers and have written something like this in `debugger.js`:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  debugger;
  var z = () => {console.log('today');}
  console.log(z());
}, 1000);
console.log('hello');
```

I then run `node debug debugger.js` in Git Bash which returns:

```
break in C:\Users\Eigenaar\OneDrive\dev\NodeJS\debugger.js:1
> 1 x = 5;
  2 setTimeout(() => {
  3   debugger;
```

I hit `c` couple of times to run through the debugging process. In the end I get:

```
< today
< undefined
```

Why is undefined being returned? What is undefined?

Comment: You know what it isn't, why not remove that? Follow the MCVE steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're logging the result of the function `z()`, which equals `console.log('today')`. `console.log` is a void function and thus returns null, which is `undefined` as a string.